# Keeping track of Django errors in production

Tags: django, error-logging, error-reporting

What would be good way way of keeping track of all errors in a production Django environment — is django-sentry the de facto way of logging this? Are there simpler and more lightweight methods available?

Thanks.

Comment: Never used it with Django, but [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/signup/r_D0g-/) really is my preference for other languages. It's a very good app with frequent update, it really worth it.